# Кириллические ссылки из приложений Flash

Tags: flash

Как сделать линк на кириллический домен (типа россия.рф) на ActionScript.

1. getURL ("http://россия.рф","_blank"); работает только из тестового окна среды разработки (Adobe Flash).
2. Не работает из браузера когда подключаешь .swf из .html файла.
3. Если ввести URL в в кодировке Punycode то будет работать тогда. Но почему не отрабатывает в кириллице из браузера?
4. Кто знает почему так происходит и как преодолеть этоу проблему?

Comment: Обновил ответ

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте [здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/Flash_Platform/113887/). Недавно попался на это. Баг фаерфокса 2007, в остальных браузерах все нормальное, но адрес лучше в виде [..].p1ai указывать. Для себя решил переадресацией флэш-запросов через лат.домен (запосы вида loadMovie('http://size.ru/my-http-proxy.php?path='+escape(url))). Знаю, что это извращение, клиент сложный был и "очень медленно и глючно" не показалось убедительным аргументом).

Куда-то делась кнопка "Добавить комментарий" о_О и [вот](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/156/tn_15683.html#main_ExternalInterface_example_in_ActionScript_2_0) ссылка) ExternalInterface работает еще в AS 1.0

Comment: да, суть бага в том, что флэш-плагин кодирует нелатинскине символы по-своему в вид %0D%0A. 
Да, еще не ругайтесь, я сначала про внутренние запросы подумал, но вполне возможно, что и здесь суть такая. 

ЗЫ: попробуйте через external делать (в as2 flash.external.externalInterface.call) и открывать через js window.open.

Comment: Спасибо, почитал, но с реальным тестированием не получается((( Ошибка адресации идет под всеми браузерами...Почему-то кириллический линк кодируется в строку ---   http://%f1%f2%ee%ef%f0%ee%f6%e5%ed%f2%ee%e2.%f0%f4/ ---- в скрипте никакой кодировки не делаю...вероятнее всего кодируется самим браузером или на стадии передачи линка из флеша в браузер...

Comment: flash.external.externalInterface.call('alert', url); 
что показывает? (это actionscript 2, вызов яваскриптового алерта, в браузере делать).
Если буквы русские (а должно бы), делайте вместо getUrl
{html} <script type="text/javascript">function wo(url){ window.open(ow);}</script> { end html }
{ flash } flash.external.externalInterface.call('wo', url);{ end flash }

Comment: не знаю я пока 3-го Actiona...

Comment: Так это код второго =) Я тоже не знаю 3.0)

Comment: помилуйте! какой же это второй!!! вот ссылка ---   http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6